# Converting PowerPoint slides to images using Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, powerpoint

I'm running an Azure Functions instance (.Net Standard 2.0.3) and need my users to be able to upload a PowerPoint presentation and return each slide as an image.

I've seen that there are a couple of 3rd party packages out there (Spire, etc) but they all rely on System.Drawing and don't work in .Net Standard.

I know the code to do it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint but again, I don't think this is supported on an Azure Functions instance.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with the Azure [Function v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#creating-1x-apps)?

Comment: No, tried with v2. Chatted with Spire, they acknowledge they have an issue which has been escallated to the devs. Finally got it working using Syncfusion in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See comment - Syncfusion was the answer